# Tap-to-focus Camera software for Windows 8.1

Tags: video, windows-8, camera

I recently bought a windows 8 tablet (in case the model it's needed it is a [Dell Venue 7140](http://www.dell.com/uk/p/dell-venue-11-pro-7000-7140/pd?ref=PD_OC)) and I've updated it to windows 8.1

This caused me to lose the opportunity to fix the focus of my camera (I've googled and it was well known that [microsoft removed that feature in windows 8.1](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-pictures/windows-81-camera-app-more-options/33f9e7ab-77dd-4d23-ab1e-c33a472f8f17) ).

So now, I'm looking for a third party software (also not-free) that allows me to focus in a similar fashion as with the ipad (in which, while recording, you tap on the screen and it focuses the camera where you tapped).

Do anyone know a good software which does something like what I described?

I tried YouCam6 but it seems it doesn't have this feature.

Thanks for your time!